# How to handle image link conversion in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a last version of TinyMCE editor and when I past image link like that `http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg` it converts automatically to `<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" data-mce-src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">`.
I've tried to catch paste_preprocess and paste_postprocess, but args.node has value of link I've been pasted.
In general, I've intrested in all methods related with image pasting into editor area.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the `autolink` plugin?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autolink/

The behavior you are describing is exactly what that plugin will do when you paste a URL to an image into TinyMCE 4.x.

If you don't want this behavior just don't load that plugin.

Comment: It is not in my plugin list. There's only `link` plugin, is it his? Here's my list: `table,fullscreen,media,preview,paste,code,image,imagetools,textcolor,link,anchor,charmap,emoticons,wordcount,hr,nonbreaking,richfilemanager,contextmenu`

Comment: I just made a TinyMCE Fiddle using your list and don't see that behavior.  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/XHfaab  I would note that `richfilemanager` is not a standard TinyMCE plugin so its possible that this plugin is responsible for this action.

Comment: This plugin I've made by myself and I am sure that he is not modify this behaviour. In your fiddle I've tried to paste link `https://s3.amazonaws.com/whisperinvest-images/default.png` and it converted to image.

Comment: After pasting this link command mceInsertContent executed twice (for link itself and img with src of that link), so I catch this events and modify this by my own rules.
So I have a final question: what happend when I'm inserting image with 'image' plugin through the popup? There's no commands called, maybe some events? In the official plugin description I didn't find anyone.

Comment: P.S. I've realized, that if I just paste link above - nothing happens, but if I open it in new tab, copy url from address string and paste into your example - it will be turned to an image.